# Rounding table corners without background image?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to round table corners (inline) without using a background image?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daBuV/)**

```
table{
    background: red;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
```

*sigh* and inline...

```
<table style="background: red;border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px;">
```

Not really sure what you mean by converting the cell to a div though.

Comment: Because you should try to never use Inline styles they are terrible when it comes to maintenance.

Comment: I know - its only one test table.

Comment: This is partial answer that is not complete, this is rounded corner, but not rounded border:
http://jsfiddle.net/daBuV/808/

The border is still square.  Maybe a trick is to have no border inside a rounded corner div?

Comment: @vdu it is definitely rounded. If you want to make it even more "round" just increase the radius number.

Comment: @Loktar see my link above, the border is not there, so the shape is rounded without border.  If you want border, the solution is still lacking.  As you can see my link above, the border is square.

http://jsfiddle.net/daBuV/810/

Comment: oooh you mean an actual border, I was just referring to the bordering edge of the table itself. Nice catch!

Answer (score 4):

This example will create rounded borders on all corners of 5 px

```
#example{
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

If you want different rounded borders on different corners, or specific rounded corners modify the below code

```
#example1{
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

Check out http://border-radius.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this. try the below code.

```
#example1 {
-moz-border-radius: 5px;  
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

For more details use [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Inline style still apply to email coding. So it is relevant.